# Else statement causes improper output

Tags: c, if-statement

I found and fixed an error in a program I needed to make for an assignment. But I don't understand why the error occurs and I would like to understand what is happening for future uses.

The program asks the user for the size of 2 int arrays, then prompts the user to enter the values these arrays will hold. It then asks the user for a range of indices from array 1 to add the values to array 2 before a given position. Then 2 more arrays are generated to show the new array 2 with the new values added from array one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fillArray(int x[], int size);

int main()
{
        int size1, size2, start, end, position;

        //getting input and creating array one
        printf("How big is array one?: ");
        scanf("%d", &size1);
        int inputArray1[size1];
        printf("Please enter the numbers for array one: ");
        fillArray(inputArray1, size1);

        //getting input and creating array two
        printf("How big is array two?: ");
        scanf("%d",&size2);
        int inputArray2[size2];
        printf("Please enter the numbers for array two: ");
        fillArray(inputArray2, size2);

        printf("Enter the start and end index of array one to be removed: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &start, &end);

        printf("Enter the position of array two to be added before: ");
        scanf("%d", &position);

        int size3 = ((end - start) + size2+1), size4 = (size1 - (end - start));
        int outputArray2[size3], kIterator=0; 


         for(int i=0; i<size3; i++){
                if(i == position){
                        for(int j=start; j<=end; j++){
                                outputArray2[i] = inputArray1[j];
                                i++;
                        }
                }else{
                //HERE IS WHERE I FIXED THE ERROR
                outputArray2[i] = inputArray2[kIterator];
                kIterator++;
                }
        }


        for(int i=0; i<size3; i++){
                printf("%d ", outputArray2[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}


//Function to fill an array with user inputs
void fillArray(int x[], int size){
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
                scanf("%d", &x[i]);
}
```

How big is array one?: 8
Please enter the numbers for array one: 9 12 8 41 38 12 67 49
How big is array two?: 3
Please enter the numbers for array two: 11 27 6
Enter the start and end index of array one to be removed: 2 5
Enter the position of array two to be added before: 1
11 8 41 38 12 32767 27

Why does this output occur? The output should be: 11 8 41 38 12 27 6
When I remove the else block but leave the code to look like:

```
for(int i=0; i<size3; i++){
     if(i == position){
         for(int j=start; j<=end; j++){
              outputArray2[i] = inputArray1[j];
              i++;
         }
     }
     //HERE IS WHERE I FIXED THE ERROR
     outputArray2[i] = inputArray2[kIterator];
     kIterator++;

}
```

Suddenly the output is correct and I don't get that large number. Why is this?

Comment: The debugger might help on this one.

Comment: Note: `size4 = (size1 - (end - start))` is unused.  Why is it there?

Comment: In the first example the index `i` was incremented (in the loop control) but you wrote nothing to that array position, after filling in the middle part. The second example is correct - you need to copy the next element anyway, whether or not you copy the middle part. So no `else` is needed.

Comment: I see it now. It's so obvious now... i gets an increment at the end of the loop that fills in the middle, and then control immediately flows to the larger loop, which means i gets incremented twice at the end of the middle-filling loop. Wonderful catch, thank you very much!

Comment: The unused variable size4 is a left over from what I deleted. As I stated, this program is part of an assignment, and I know sometimes this site is used to copy paste code, so I didn't want this to be used in the future for such purposes.

Comment: It's helpful to *direct* your replies to the commenters, for example your most recent comment would be better as: @chux . . .

Comment: @A.Miranda I would have commented like this to demonstrate the style, but a) the comment reaches the Original Poster anyway, and b) I wanted to draw chux's attention to your answer to his comment, and c) only one @ is allowed per comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you, I will keep this in mind going forward.

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign the 5th member of the `outputArray2` array. Placing some printfs:

```
     for(int i = 0; i < size3; i++){
            if (i == position) {
                    for(int j = start; j <= end; j++) {
                            printf("i=%d j=%d\n", i, j);
                            outputArray2[i] = inputArray1[j];
                            i++;
                    }
            } else {
                    printf("i=%d kIterator=%d\n", i, kIterator);
                    outputArray2[i] = inputArray2[kIterator];
                    kIterator++;
            }
    }
```

You can see:

```
i=0 kIterator=0
i=1 j=2
i=2 j=3
i=3 j=4
i=4 j=5
i=6 kIterator=1
```

`i` is never equal `5`, thus `outputArray2[5]` is never initialized and has uninitialized value. Why is that? Because the `i` gets incremented twice.
Imagine you are on the line `outputArray2[i] = inputArray1[j];` the last time with `i = 4` and `j =  5 = end`. Then the next line `i++` makes i=5, then `j++` from `for` increments `j = 6` which is greater then `end` so the `for(int j = start; j <= end; j++)` exits. Then the `i++` statement from the first `for(int i = 0; i < size3; i++)` get's executed thus incrementing the `i` second time to `6`! You can also fix the code better with:

```
     for(int i = 0; i < size3; i++){
            if (i == position) {
                    for(int j = start; j <= end; j++) {
                            outputArray2[i] = inputArray1[j];
                            i++;
                    }
                    i--;
            } else {
                    outputArray2[i] = inputArray2[kIterator];
                    kIterator++;
            }
    }
```

This method is better then your code, because when `end == size3` then the loop doesn't try to assign the value out of bound for `outputArray2` (ie. `outputArray2[size3] = smth`). (It's all assuming, that `position+(end-start) <= size3`, which you don't check anyway).